# Use $HOSTNAME in upstart script

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, upstart

(Can|how do) I use `$HOSTNAME` in an Ubuntu upstart script like this:

```
start on started foo
stop on stopped foo

exec someexecutable -n "$HOSTNAME""_bb"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since "/etc/network/if-*.d/upstart" scripts are shell scripts, you can use an environment variable such as $HOSTNAME.

Here is what I recommend: set it first with the value you want to be sure of what is inside, like this:

```
HOSTNAME=`hostname -s`

exec someexecutable -n "$HOSTNAME""_bb"
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. You however have to wrap it in a `script/ end script block` to have upstart execute it.